# Unable to configure Logback from a custom directory using the logback.configurationFile parameter

Tags: java, maven, logging, logback

I want to change the default directory of the logback.configurationFile in order to give a new directory to it so that it looks for logback.xml in that directory but it doesn't work. How can I do that?

```
public class App{
    static{System.setProperty("logback.configurationFile","C:/Users/p.khaleghi/");}
    public static void main(String args[]) {


        if(args[0] == null){
            System.out.println("There is no input file in the right directory");
        }
        else{
            Calculator calculator = new Calculator();
            calculator.calculate(args[0]);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `logback.configurationFile` system property is a path to a configuration file, it is **not** a path to a directory which might contain a configuration file.

So, assuming there is a file named `other-logback.xml` in this directory: `C:/Users/p.khaleghi/` then you can tell Logback to configure itself from that file by either:

- Running with the following JVM system parameter: `-Dlogback.configurationFile=C:/Users/p.khaleghi/other-logback.xml`
- Using a static initialiser in your class to set that system property: `static{System.setProperty("logback.configurationFile","C:/Users/p.khaleghi/other-logback.xml");}`. Note: this approach will only work if this static initialiser runs **before** Logback is initiaised so if you had this static initialiser and a static Logger declaration in the same class then Logback could be initialised before the `logbackConfigurationFile` property is set.

More details [in the docs](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#configFileProperty)

Comment: what if i have multiple configuration files?i want to give an address to it so it looks for it

Comment: Logback's configuration discovery mechanism is described [here](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#auto_configuration), you override this mechanism when you pass in the system parameter: `logback.configurationFile` but that parameter has to point at a **specific file**. That's just how it works. If you supply a directory (rather than a specific file) in that system parameter and if that directory contains multiple configuration files then how could Logback know which one to use?

Comment: but i have another problem now.this doesn't work when i make my project jar file and run this command:java -Dlogback.debug=true -jar target\Calculator-6.0.0.jar

Comment: What - specifically - does "this doesn't work" mean?

Comment: it does not find my logback.xml which is in my desired directory

Comment: It's possible that somewhere inside Calculator-6.0.0.jar a class instances a Logger statically **before** the static initialiser which sets `logback.configurationFile` is run. Or perhaps whatever system you are running this command on does not have access to the configured `logback.configurationFile` address. You could side step this by passing `logback.configurationFile` in as a system param in the same way as you are passing in `logback.debug`. For example: `-Dlogback.configurationFile=C:/Users/p.khaleghi/logback.xml` though you must ensure that this address is readable.

Comment: i want to set logback.debug true so that i can see why it doesn't find my logback.xml    but this command does not work : java -Dlogback.debug=true -jar target\Calculator-6.0.0.jar      it works fine when my project is not jar

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156338/discussion-between-pegahk-and-glitch).